# To determine distribution function of a quantity using other distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $A=B/C$ where distributions of $B$ and $C$ are known to follow exponential distributions. Is there a method to determine distribution function of $A$ using the knowledge of the distributions of $B$ and $C$?

Comment: No, if the joint distribution is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [Ratio Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution) between two exponential distributions.   This requires knowledge of the *joint distribution* of the variables (ie: how-or-if the random variables are related).

If $A=B/C$ then $f_A(x) = {\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R} \lvert{z}\rvert\, f_{B,C}(zx, z)\operatorname d z$

---

In the *special case* where $B,C$ are *independent* exponential r.v. with rate parameters $\lambda_B, \lambda_C$, then $$f_A(x) ~{= \mathbf 1_{x\in(0;\infty)}\cdot{\displaystyle\int_0^\infty} \lambda_B\lambda_C z\, \mathsf e^{-(\lambda_B x+\lambda_C)z}\operatorname d z \\ = \dfrac{\lambda_B\lambda_C}{(\lambda_B x+\lambda_C)^2}~\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;\infty)} }$$